# Solspace Calendar Minus Bootstrap

Tags: calendar, solspace

Solspace Calendar is a great calendar add-on, and the templates are great - as long as you are using Bootstrap.  However, we mainly use Zurb Foundation.

I'm just staring to dive in, but I'm curious if anyone has reconfigured for Foundation?

Comment: Just curious as I never heard of Zurb Foundation before just took a look.. How much of an advantage does it have over using bootstrap if I may ask? Or is it just a personal preference?

Comment: We are just about to implement it on Foundation as well so commenting for notifications. I know they factored in Foundation on their Freeform plugin if I recall correct.

Comment: Justin, yes it's personal preference.

Comment: I just went in and changed class names and stuff and got it working with the XY grid. was a little tedious but not that difficult.

Comment: Has Solspace Calendar been updated for Zurb Foundation yet?